# ¿cómo eliminar elementos nulos o vacíos de un array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

mi pregunta es.

Tengo un arreglo con esta estructura:

```
$arrelgo = [
    0 => [
        'cedula' => 123455, 
        'correo' => 'micorreo@dominio.com'
    ],
    1 => [
        'cedula' => 123455,
        'correo' => ''
    ],
    2 => [
        'cedula' => 123455,
        'correo' => ''
    ]
]
```

Lo que deseo es eliminar los dos arreglos donde el correo tiene una cadena vacía o tenga un valor nulo dando como resultado un arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```
$arrelgo = [
    'cedula' => 123455, 
    'correo' => 'micorreo@dominio.com'
]
```

Agradezco enormemente la ayuda. Buen día.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nulos o vacíos... uno de los grandes dilemas de la informática.

**¿Qué es nulo, qué es vacío?** Si no se responde a esa pregunta, por lo demás más filosófica que informática, será difícil escribir un código funcional en algunas situaciones.

Consideremos este array:

```
$arrDatos = 
[
   0 => [
        'cedula' => 123455, 
        'correo' => 'micorreo@dominio.com'
    ],
   1 => [
        'cedula' => 123456,
        'correo' => ''
    ],
   2 => [
        'cedula' => 123457,
        'correo' => ' '
    ],
   3 => [
        'cedula' => 123458,
        'correo' => FALSE
    ]    
,
   4 => [
        'cedula' => 123459,
        'correo' => 0
    ]    
,
   5 => [
        'cedula' => 123460,
        'correo' => 'otro@correo.com'
    ]        
,
   6 => [
        'cedula' => 123461,
        'correo' => NULL
    ]   
,
   7 => [
        'cedula' => 123462,
        'correo' => '0'
    ]   

]
;
```

En el caso de querer como resultado final solamente los valores que tengan realmente un email o algo que se le parezca, habrá que actuar sobre los elementos, porque como puedes ver, los índices `2, 3, 4, 6 y 7` nos plantean el problema filosófico de *lo nulo y lo vacío*.

En este caso, `trim` nos ayuda bastante. Y todavía la función no es perfecta. Quizá para este caso concreto, habría que aplicar también a cada clave `correo` un validador de email.

No obstante, creo que este código hace el trabajo que necesitas:

```
$arrFinal = array_filter($arrDatos, function($item){
    $notEmpty=count($item) == count(array_filter(array_map('trim', $item)));
    return $notEmpty;
});


/*Si quieres re-indexar el array final*/
sort($arrFinal);
```

---

**Salida:**

Array final sin reindexar

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cedula] => 123455
            [correo] => micorreo@dominio.com
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [cedula] => 123460
            [correo] => otro@correo.com
        )

)
```

---

Array final reindexado

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cedula] => 123455
            [correo] => micorreo@dominio.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cedula] => 123460
            [correo] => otro@correo.com
        )

)
```

---

### Probar el código

Aquí puedes ver un <kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/NGBE87521)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas con él.

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfecto para mí. Fue justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @SandersGutierrez Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo como:

```
for($i = count($arreglo); $i > 0; $i--){
     if(empty($arreglo[$i]['cedula']) && empty($arreglo[$i]['correo'])){
         unset($arreglo[$i]);
     }
}
```

Revisa la sintaxis, que lo hice de memoria.

Mirate la documentación oficial de unset() para mas info: http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php

Comment: Cae en un bucle infinito, parece que quieres recorrer el array desde el final hasta el principio y la variable que utilizas para iterar le sumas en lugar de restar.

Comment: @ErnestoRM Cierto, perdona, corrigo ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

Una solución un poco más general que se abstrae de la estructura original del array.

```
    $arreglo = [
        0 => [
            'cedula' => 123455,
            'correo' => 'micorreo@dominio.com'
        ],
        1 => [
            'cedula' => 123455,
            'correo' => ''
        ],
        2 => [
            'cedula' => 123455,
            'correo' => ''
        ]
    ];


foreach ($arreglo as $dato){
    //suponemos que todas las claves tienen un valor
    $completo = true;
    //recorremos cada una de las arrays en busca de claves vacías
    foreach($dato as $clave=>$valor){
        //si encontramos alguna clave vacía lo marcamos como incompleto
        if(empty($valor)){
            $completo = false;
        }
    }
    //si no se ha uncontrado ninguna clave vacía
    if($completo){
       //añadimos el array al array de resultados
       $nuevoArreglo[]=$dato;
    }

}
print_r($nuevoArreglo);
```

Básicamente recorre cada array que integra el array principal buscando claves vacías, si todas las claves tienen un valor lo añade al array que dará como resultado un array con todas las claves llenas

Comment: Esto comprueba si el valor del array es vació, no si el campo de email esta vació.

Comment: Cierto, lo comento en la solución. Comprueba que todos las campos del array estén llenos y por lo tanto, también comprueba si lo está el campo 'email'. Es una solución más general y que valdría, por ejemplo si también estuviera vacío el campo 'cedula' o si el array tuviera más valores.

Comment: Es una solución tan valida como las demás, esperemos a que el OP escoja la que mas se adecue a su problema.

Comment: ¡Por supuesto! nunca he pretendido lo contrario, es una simple alternativa. En ningún momento he ensalzado mi respuesta respecto de las demás. Con lo de solución general, no estoy diciendo que sea mejor, simplemente que se abstrae de la estructura del array original, nada más. OP valorará como siempre la que mas se adecue, sea cual sea, yo no estoy aquí para competir si no para aportar. ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución valida respecto a la de @montes18295 puede ser algo asi.

```
$arrayAux = array();
foreach ($arreglo as $valor){
    if($valor['correo'] != null && !empty($valor['correo'])){
         array_push($arrayAux, $valor);
    }
}
$arreglo = $arrayAux;
var_dump($arreglo);
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución más sencilla se consigue usando la función `array_filter` la cual recibe un `$array` como primer argumento y una función `callback` como segundo argumento.

Esta es su sintaxis:

```php
array_filter($arr, callback)
```

Esta devuelve un nuevo `array` pero sin aquellos elementos no cumplen no satisfacen el filtro aplicado mediante la función `callback`.

Entonces esta sería la solución:

```php
$arrelgo = [
    0 => [
        'cedula' => 123455, 
        'correo' => 'micorreo@dominio.com'
    ],
    1 => [
        'cedula' => 123455,
        'correo' => ''
    ],
    2 => [
        'cedula' => 123455,
        'correo' => ''
    ]
];


$nuevoArreglo = array_filter($arreglo, function ($arr) {
    return ($arr['correo'] != null || $arr['correo'] != '');
});

print_r($nuevoArreglo);

// Output

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [dni] => 123456
//             [email] => email@domain.com
//         )
// )
```